# Access Internal VM host only network from host in virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nat

I have a vm network for a project that I must test against pings from the
outside, the thing is I can't set it up to check.

Here's the layout:

```
Windows Host :
             VBOX
              ↑
     nat adapter port forwarded (ssh -p2222 vm@localhost) 
             GW01 server
              ↓
     host-only adapter enp0s8 IP:192.168.1.4
             ⇅
             MG01 internal dhcp server IP:192.168.1.3 gateway 192.168.1.4
             APP01 server gets ip from MG01 192.168.1.6
             CL01  client gets ip from MG01 192.168.1.5
```

How can I ping an ip in the internal network e.g `192.168.1.5` from the host?

Update:
Is it possibl to reach the host only ips using redirects configured in iptables on my GW01 server?
given that port redirection is configured between GW01 and the host, Is it possible to ssh APP01 using ssh -p2222 vm@localhost ?
because this is exactly what I need

Comment: Host-Only is designed to be isolated. Set it up as NAT to do what you wish.  Access but isolated tends to be a contradiction.

Comment: homework says this is the setup, i just need to block traffic from outside (NAT) to inside except for specific ports i have iptables setup and my hostonly has access to internet through the nat adapter but i need to access my machines from outside

Comment: Ask your class. Isolation and connection at the same time does not usually work well.

Comment: Going out on a limb, `NATservice` (not just `NAT`) may be what you're look for. [Relevant documentation here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html).